# Base64 iOS vs Android different results

Tags: android, ios, arrays, swift, base64

I'm doing a base64 encoding from a byte array but the result in Android and iOS is different.

My original array in iOS is: [0, 0, 0, 1, 104, 206, 6, 242] or equivalent in Android: [0, 0, 0, 1, 104, -50, 6, -14]

Method used for base64 in Android (working as expected):

```
Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Method used in iOS (not working):

```
Data(bytes).base64EncodedString()
```

Android result as String:

```
aM4NiA==
```

iOS result as String:

```
AAAAAWjOBvI=
```

I want to get the same result in iOS than Android. Actually I have a code in Android working and I'm porting it to iOS so I want fix it in iOS if possible.

Comment: If you use this online tool: https://base64.guru/converter/decode/hex `aM4NiA==` <=b64=>`68ce0d88` & `AAAAAWjOBvI=` <=b64=>`0000000168ce06f2 ` So according to input being `[0, 0, 0, 1, 104, 206, 6, 242]`, iOS code seems correct, while Android one is strange...

Comment: I did a mistake porting the code because I forgot to remove 0, 0, 0, 1 bytes from the array. After that, all is working fine.